# How do I pick a line and write it to an external file?

Tags: cygwin, original-vim

I'm searching through a big text file and want to copy certain lines to another file - there is no specific pattern,
I need to visually inspect and copy those lines to an external file.
The command `:2400p` prints line 2400 to the Vim command line, but I can't get it to write (append) it to another file.
I could use more or less but not sure that would help any better.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `:[range]w >> file` to append the given range to the given file. If the file does not yet exist, use the `!` argument to the `:w` command to force writing the new file.

So this means you can use `:2400w >> my_custom.txt` to write line 2400 to my_custom.txt file, or if your cursor is on the current line already, you can simply use `:.w >> my_custom.txt` (which could then e.g. be used by a `:g` command, to write lines matching a certain pattern).